# Convert vector unsigned char to string/int

Tags: c++, ios

i did try to search how, but not find best way.
I'm working on a game using cubeia firebase server, connect using socket. Below is packet that received from server:

```
--TableSnapshotPacket
 |--int32_t tableid;
 |--std::string address;
 |--std::string name;
 |--int16_t capacity;
 |--int16_t seated;
 |--std::vector<Param> params;
                 |--std::string key;
                 |--int8_t type;
                 |--vector<uint8_t> value;
```

My problem is parser key value of Param to string and int. 
I want read `key == 'N'` for string
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlv9y.png

and `key == 'M'` for int
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kjynp.png

As you can see, `vector<uint8_8> value` contain '\0' at first, so i got problem on parser this. 
Below is my way, can convert to string but i feel not good, and can't convert to int.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ip->value.size(); i++)
{
    if (i < 2)
        value.push_back(' ');
    else
        value.push_back(ip->value[i]);

    printf("%d", ip->value[i]);
}
```

Anyone has best ideal?
Here is code in java: `https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDn9b.png`

Answer (score 0):

According to the images, the cases are:

-**int**: the `value` vector contain 4 elements with the int value (that could in forward order or in reverse order). You could read the int, first checking that the size is equal to 4, and casting the vector pointer to int32_t (for the forward order). Example:

```
if (ip->value.size() != sizeof(int32_t)) {
   // handle error
}
int32_t int_value = *static_cast<int32_t*>(&(ip->value[0]));
```

For the inverse order:

```
if (ip->value.size() != sizeof(int32_t)) {
   // handle error
}
int32_t int_value = static_cast<uint8_t>(ip->value[3]) |
                   (static_cast<uint8_t>(ip->value[2]) << 8) |
                   (static_cast<uint8_t>(ip->value[1]) << 16) |
                   (static_cast<uint8_t>(ip->value[0]) << 24);
```

Sorry by the cast, are needed because of narrowing conversion (ex: when value[...] = 0x93 = -109.

-**string**: two ideas, the string in write in reverse order (by this the first element is *\0*, most probably) in this case:

```
std::string str_value;
for (int idx = ip->value.size() - 1; idx > 0; idx--) {
   str_value += ip->value[idx];
}
```

The string is write in forward order, and is needed to skip the first character (probably the first 2). In this case.

```
if (ip->value.size() < 2) {
   // handle error
}
std::string str_value(ip->value.begin() + 2, ip->value.end());
```

Comment: Thank NetVipeC for this answer. I was try with Int, but don't success. Here M can be 10, 100, 2000, 10000, 50000 or 200000 and need get that value.

Comment: Could you please post a specific case, the vector is a continued memory location [0], [1], [2], [3], in case of the image would be: 0x0,0x0,0x0,0xd, in the sample code the first version of read int: `int32_t int_value = *static_cast<int32_t*>(&(ip->value[0]));` would read 0x0d000000 (as little endian) in case you need to read 0x0000000d (as big endian), the second code with the cast is neccesary.